# Passing HTML input file as the parameter of Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am pretty new this area and I started firebase cloud function 2 days ago.

Sorry, I am still a student so I might not understand clearly some documentation.

I tried to figure out how the parameter is passed from my client-side javascript to firebase cloud function.

my cloud function

```js
exports.OCR = functions.https.onCall((req) => {
  const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
  // Creates a client
  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
  console.log(req);
  // Performs label detection on the image file
  client
    .documentTextDetection(req)
    .then((results) => {
      console.log("Entered");
      console.log(req);
      const fullTextAnnotation = results[0].fullTextAnnotation;
      console.log(fullTextAnnotation.text);
      return results[0].fullTextAnnotation.text;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
      return "error";
    });
})
```

I am using firebase cloud function and Google Vision API.

actually I tried to pass the parameter like this

My client side coe

```js
document.getElementById("fileInput").click();
    var file = document.getElementById("fileInput");
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        // Do something with the image file.
        var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        console.log(file);
        console.log(tmppath);
        //var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recette-f3ef5.appspot.com/o/FB1.gif?alt=media&token=28727220-181c-440e-87ae-4808b5c9ba28";
        OCR(file)
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

and it did not work. I always got null return when I trigger the function.

So, my question is that how can I pass the file (HTML INPUT TAG) to my cloud function?

p.s: when I tried the code with node the_code.js it works.

Comment: If you are working with code, you should copy that into the issue directly so it's easy to read and search.  You might also want to read this in order to refine your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thx for advising! I changed it! @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Cloud Node.js library [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient#documentTextDetection) the `documentTextDetection` function should receive a JS object like this:

```
var image = {
  source: {imageUri: 'gs://path/to/image.jpg'}
};

vision.documentTextDetection(image).then(response => {
  // doThingsWith(response);
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

The `file` you are passing to `OCR` function has probably a different structure than that defined in documentation.

There are some variants to this:

> If the key is `source`, the value should be another object containing
>   `imageUri` or `filename` as a key and a string as a value.
>
> If the key is `content`, the value should be a Buffer.

So your code should look something like this.

```
    console.log(tmppath);
    //var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recette-f3ef5.appspot.com/o/FB1.gif?alt=media&token=28727220-181c-440e-87ae-4808b5c9ba28";
    image = {source: {imageUri: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recette-f3ef5.appspot.com/o/FB1.gif?alt=media&token=28727220-181c-440e-87ae-4808b5c9ba28'}}
    OCR(image)
```

Please provide complete error messages and description of what is `file`..